# .NET Core API & React view in local network?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

Right now im using xamp to run my php app in a pc that works as a server. All the other pcs in the local network can access to the app by the url of the server pc.
Now i want to build the app using ASP .NET Core to make an API and React to consume that api. Is there a way to run the api and view in a pc (local server) and that the other pcs in the network can access to the app?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you create a Proof of Concept?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! This is a very general question, while StackOverflow is typically geared more towards specific coding help. The short answer is yes, ASP.NET Core allows you to develop an API / App and host it on Windows / Linux / Etc. Check out their documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-3.1